# Center datetimes of resampled time series

Tags: python, pandas

When I resample a Pandas time series to reduce the number of data points, the timestamp of each resulting datapoint is at the start of each resampling bin. When overplotting graphs with different resampling rates, this causes an apparent shift of the data. How can I "center" the timestamp of the resampled data in its bin, whatever the resample rate?

What I get now is (when resampling to one hour):

```
In [12]: d_r.head()
Out[12]: 
2017-01-01 00:00:00    0.330567
2017-01-01 01:00:00    0.846968
2017-01-01 02:00:00    0.965027
2017-01-01 03:00:00    0.629218
2017-01-01 04:00:00   -0.002522
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

what I want is:

```
In [12]: d_r.head()
Out[12]: 
2017-01-01 00:30:00    0.330567
2017-01-01 01:30:00    0.846968
2017-01-01 02:30:00    0.965027
2017-01-01 03:30:00    0.629218
2017-01-01 04:30:00   -0.002522
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

MWE showing apprarent shift:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
Minimal working example:

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn
seaborn.set()

plt.ion()

# sample data
t = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00', '2017-01-01 10:00', freq='1min')
d = pd.Series(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 7, len(t))), index=t)


d_r = d.resample('1h').mean()

d.plot()
d_r.plot()
```

[image: Apparent shift of resampled data]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to use the midpoint in general. There is the `label`-parameter, but that only has the options `right` and `left`. However, in a concrete case as this you can explicitly offset the resampled timestamp with the `loffset`-parameter:

```
d.resample('1h', loffset='30min').mean()
```

(edit: Use `30min` instead of `30T` as that is more readable: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

Comment: loffset could work, but it's not ideal since I'll be resampling to several different scales (minutely, hourly, daily) and I'd have to specify each offset manually.

Answer (score 3):

The `loffset` keyword argument seems to be deprecated soon.

In my opinion, the nicest way to do it that I know of is the following:

```
d_r = d.shift(0.5, freq='1h').resample('1h').mean()
```

Compared to using the `loffset` keyword this has the advantage that the resulting timestamps are at full hours.

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding 30 minutes with timedelta to index?

```
df.index = df.index + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

matthme's solution is a good one, but it doesn't solve the main problem with `resample`, i.e. the time tags are always separated by the `rule` that is chosen for resampling (1h in your case), and this can lead to a wrong time tag at the beginning and/or end of your time series if the duration is not an integer multiple of the `rule`.

The best thing you can do is average your time series and use the result as the time tag (i.e. the index of your DataFrame). Unfortunately, the `resample` method can't operate on `datetime` objects, so you have to transform it to `timestamp`, apply the average to the resampled DataFrame, and convert the `timestamp` back to `datetime`. This will automatically center the time tags inside your time binning interval and it will adjust the tags at the beginning and end of the time series. No need for shifting in this case.

A working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


t = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00', '2017-01-01 10:00', freq='1min')
timestamp = t.astype('int64') // 10**9  # covert datetime to timestamp in seconds
d = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': t,
                  'timestamp': timestamp,
                  'd': np.sin(np.linspace(0, 7, len(t)))}, 
                 index=t)
t_avg = '1h'

d_r = d.shift(0.5, freq=t_avg).resample(t_avg).mean()

d_r2 = d.resample(t_avg).mean()
d_r2.index = pd.to_datetime(d_r2['timestamp'], unit='s')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(d['datetime'], d['d'], label='unsampled')
ax.plot(d_r.index, d_r['d'], 'o', label='shifted resample')
ax.plot(d_r2.index, d_r2['d'], 'D', label='time average resample')
plt.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]